# Error on Boot after Install

Tags: boot, 14.10

I installed Ubuntu 14.10 from usb after creating the usb using the usb creator. When the machine rebooted I got just a purple screen. I then rebooted and I got a screen with some boot options ie Ubuntu Ubuntu special options or memory checks. When I select the Ubuntu option it gives me a black screen with the following message.

[    1.554124] i8042: No controller found

I am a noob to Linux not a noob to pc's but used Dos / Windows for 20+ years I am not sure where my install is failing but I have installed twice with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely a problem with BIOS Legacy USB support. Check to see if your BIOS has the necessary support.